# is Assigning object to statically created object cause memory leak in C++?

Tags: c++, object, memory-leaks, static

Im New to C++ and i know that dynamically created object should be freed manually,
but i wounder if Object created statically as below would it cause memory leak when assigning it to another object or the new object overrides the old one, supposing we have a Class named `Test`.

```
Test t;
t = Test() ;
```

Comment: If you don't use `new`, you can't have a memory leak (oversimplification but it's fine for beginners)

Comment: It's not clear to me which object you are concerned about. Are you worried the original `Test` that `t` referred to is leaked or are you worried that the temporary `Test` in `Test()` might leak?

Comment: And if you simply never use `new` directly, you will almost never have to worry about memory leaks. Use `std::string`, `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` instead. That is not only for this reason highly adviced.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes i mean the first scenario you pointed out, what will happen to old allocated space at first line of code?

Comment: @M.eid You may be confused by other languages like Java or Python. C++ uses value semantics. `t = Test();` copies the value (or state) of a temporary `Test` object that is default constructed into `t`. But `t` continues to be `t` as long as it exists. In those other languages, object variables work more like pointer or handles to objects, you could change which `Test` the variable `t` refers to. One consequence is that it's impossible to change the address of an object.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux as understood the term "overrides" is true in this case?

Comment: @M.eid: No, in C++ the word "overrides" is used in the context of virtual functions and their implementations in derived classes. None of that applies here.

Comment: @M.eid You might be thinking of the term "overwrite" because assignment often "overwrites" an object's state with a new one. But it isn't a term defined by the C++ language. `override` has a specific language meaning related to polymorphism and `virtual` functions that doesn't apply here.

Comment: @MSalters yes you are right, I meant  the real effect in the memory

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux thank you so much and everyone, it's now very clear to me

Comment: I wondered the same and the replies here don't make me rest assured: `Test t;` default-constructs a `Test` and allocates memory (on stack?) which gets freed upon leaving the scope that statement is in. Now assume `Test` is a custom class without a custom copy-constructor and the RHS of line 2 of the original question is a function call returning a copy of `Test` (which was also created in that function "on the stack" (without `new`) and returned), there are 2 `Test` now occupying memory. Will the copy assignment copy the returned data to the space occupied by `t` and free the returned space?

Comment: adding to my previous comment I guess `Test t; t=funcReturningTest();` is only high-level shorthand for `Test t; Test s=funcReturningTest(); t=s;` in which case the data returned by `funcReturningTest()` is in the same scope as `Test t` and thus will get freed when that scope is left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is Assigning object to statically created object cause memory leak in C++?

Not in general. And not for any well designed class.

But if the assignment operator has a memory leak, then invoking the operator would indeed cause memory to leak.